# How To Use WebAPI 2 and RouteAttribute to POST Complex Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI 2 Controller as follows (simplified here):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Hierarchy")]
public class HierarchyController : ApiController {

  [HttpPost]
  [Route("LevelFiltered")]
  public async Task<GCAResponse<List<SelectableFilterItem>>> GetSomething() {
    ...
  } // GetSomething
} // HierarchyController
```

When I call that function with a jQuery ajax call as follows...

```
$.ajax({
  url: $scope.URLs.Test,
  contentType: "application/json",
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert("here");
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(errorThrown);
}).always(function () {

}); // ajax
```

...It works.

However, when I simply add an integer property and pass it along I get a 404 error.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("LevelFiltered")]
public async Task<GCAResponse<List<SelectableFilterItem>>> GetSomething(int id) {
  ...
} // GetSomething
```

Client call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $scope.URLs.Test,
  contentType: "application/json",
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify({ "id": 1 })
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert("here");
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(errorThrown);
}).always(function () {

}); // ajax
```

I know I could pass the ID in the route with:

```
[Route("LevelFiltered/{id}")]
```

And I have done that with primitive objects.  However, my real signature needs to be the following:

```
public async Task<GCAResponse<List<SelectableFilterItem>>> GetSomething(FilterViewTypes filterType, string parentID, FilterSelections filters)
```

Where filterType is an enumeration and filters is a complex object with arrays.

I have tried what must be every article out here on the internet and have not had any success.  I have to be close or the parameterless version would not work.  If all of my properties were primitive objects I would just tack them onto the URL.

So how can I pass multiple, complex objects to a Web API 2 controller from the client side.  This is an MVC 5 website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out by phoning a friend.

Apparently you can only pass 1 (One, Uno, Hana, Single) complex object in via WebAPI.  So I wrapped my 3 desired parameters into a single object (model) and passed that long.  Note that you do Not have to pass the WebAPI signature property name in on the ajax call.  Meaning my property is called `input` but it is not in the ajax call below.

So you can following along from the beginning, here is the updated WebAPI controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Hierarchy")]
public class HierarchyController : ApiController  {

  [HttpPost]
  [Route("LevelFiltered")]
  public async Task<GCAResponse<List<SelectableFilterItem>>> GetUsersFilteredHierarchyItems(LevelFilterParameters input) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Nothing changed except for merging the 3 parameters into 1 which I called `LevelFilterParameters` and placed in my `Model` folder.  Here is that class:

```
public class LevelFilterParameters {
  public FilterViewTypes FilterType { get; set; }
  public string ParentID { get; set; }
  public FilterSelections Filters { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the updated javascript call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $scope.URLs.Test,
  contentType: "application/json",
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify({ FilterType: 1, ParentID: null, Filters: UsersFilters })
}).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  alert("here");
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(errorThrown);
}).always(function () {

}); // ajax
```

Works like a champ.  Thank you Kyle.